# jQuery load() form serialize

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, load

i've got a problem with the load Methode from jQuery.
Here my code:

```js
$('#form').submit(function( event ) {
    $('.response').load('responseData.php?'+
                                     $('#form').serialize());
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
 <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
 <input type="text" name="text" id="text" /><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Speichern" class="submit"/>
</form>

<div class="response"></div>
```

The file responseData.php exists. But when I click submit, i get an '500 internal error'. 
The path is correct it is:
**http://domain.de/data/responseData.php?title=test&text=test**

Do you know what's going on here? I'm really desperated.

Thank you!

Comment: The 500 internal error means, that there is an error in your .php file

Comment: Your client script is correct

Comment: Could you post your PHP code, so we can help you? :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, i've got an error in my php :)